# Functional analysis: subspace of a separable Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, brownian-motion

The [Karhunen-Loève Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosambi%E2%80%93Karhunen%E2%80%93Lo%C3%A8ve_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20the%20theory%20of%20stochastic,Fourier%20series%20representation%20of%20a) is concerned about a continuous second-order process $X=\{X_t, t\in [a,b]\}$, defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A, P)$.

The Theorem allows us to apply the following expansion:

$$X_t=\Sigma_{k=1}^\infty Z_ke_k(t), \quad t\in [a,b],$$
where $\{e_k\}$ are the eigenfunctions of the (Hilbert-Schmidt integral operator) linear operator $T_{K_X}:L^2[a,b]\to L^2[a,b]$ and $\{Z_k\}$ are zero mean pairwise orthogonal random variables with corresponding variance $\lambda_k$ (the eigenvalues associated to $e_k$).

It is known that $\{e_k\}$ form an orthonormal system in $L^2[a,b]$. I infer that the space spanned by $\{e_k\}$, named $V$, is a subspace of $L^2[a,b]$. If I equip $L^2[a,b]$ with the standard inner product $<,>$, then $(L^2[a,b],<,>)$ is a **separable Hilbert space**.

**Question** Is $(V,<,>)$ again a separable Hilbert space?

Comment: You shouldn’t even need separability of $L^2$. Since you are taking the closure of the span of countable many vectors, you can take the set of all finite linear combinations of these vectors with rational weights and this will form a countable sense subset of $V$. Hence $V$ is separable.